# Command for automatic activate changes in Oracle Weblogic Server after deployment

Tags: weblogic

Firstly connecting to the weblogic server using connect command then

I am deploying ears using the deploy command and i have many ears to be deployed so after every ear deployment i have to go to the console and click on activate changes 
Is there any command for activate changes

```
connect(username, password, urladmin)

deploy(applName,deploymentFile,targets=deploymentTarget,appversion='v1',timeout=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an activate command.

activate([timeout], [block])

"Activates changes saved during the current editing session but not yet deployed. This command prints a message if a server restart is required for the changes that are being activated."

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WLSTC/reference.htm#WLSTC254